# Will the new MCC 2017 laws apply on old cricket match stats?

Tags: cricket, statistics

There are a whole lot of MCC 2017 changes coming up: [MCC Laws of Cricket 2017](https://www.lords.org/assets/Uploads/MCC-Laws-of-Cricket-2017-Code-Final-8-May.pdf)

Summary: [Law Summary Paper](https://www.lords.org/assets/Uploads/Law-Summary-Paper-Interactive-V6.pdf)

Do these changes apply to old matches which would modify their stats slightly?

Comment: Other than the "handled the ball" to "obstructing the field" change, is there anything else which could affect a match's statistics?

Comment: There are some no ball changes. Trying to get my head around these changes atm.

Comment: Ah yes, you're right. No ball + (leg) byes would previously (old laws 26.1, 26.2(c)(ii)) be scored as more than one no ball, but in the new laws (18.10.2, 23.1, 23.2.3) it's one no ball + a separate count of (leg) byes.

Comment: I guess that would be a hard one to change for old matches :) I'm leaning that old matches won't be affected by these new changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are potentially two changes in the new Laws which could affect match statistics:

1. The merging of the "handled the ball" dismissal into "obstructing the field". Given the small number of handled the ball dismissals which have happened in top-level cricket, it would be possible to re-write the score books to change all these into "obstructing the field". Frankly, all that's going to do is to change the answers to some trivia questions - e.g. "How many people have been given out obstructing the field in Test cricket?" would change from just [Len Hutton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obstructing_the_field#Dismissals_in_international_cricket) to a set of eight people.
2. A change in scoring when byes or leg byes are scored off a no-ball. In the old Laws, this would be scored as multiple no-balls (and thus all debited to the bowler) whereas in the new Laws it would be one no ball and a separate account of byes or leg byes (thus leading to only one run being debited to the bowler). As even for international cricket, full ball-by-ball scores don't exist from before the mid-1990s, it's just not possible to do this for a lot of earlier matches. More generally, this change is similar to that made in the early 1980s when wides and no-balls were first debited to the bowler - while some analyses have been performed under the "new" way of doing things, the official scorecard stands as it was scored when the match was played.